# React Table is over SideBar

Tags: css, reactjs, react-data-table-component

Is there any css property on a sidebar, or div, or table, that I'm missing to send my content underneath the Sidebar when opened?

I'm using react-data-table-component.

DataTable over SideBar:

[image]

**DataTable Css:**

```
#RTable-7 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 3px solid #ddd;
    width: 100%;
}

#RTable-7 td, #RTable-7 th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
}

#RTable-7 tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#RTable-7 tr:hover {
    /* background-color: #ddd; */
    background-color: #eea2a2;
}

#RTable-7 th {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

**SideBar Css:**

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #060b26;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-menu {
    background-color: #060b26;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    transition: 850ms;
}
  
.nav-menu.active {
    left: 0;
    transition: 350ms;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to give the `z-index` value of the `.nav-menu` a value higher than that of the table. Try this

```
.nav-menu {
    z-index: 10 !important; // increase it if 10 doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Haha what a f*cking good advice man thanks, that z-index had to be in the .nav-menu.active class instead, but It was on the right direction so thanks.